# Automatic indentation for Python in Notepad++

Tags: python, notepad++, indentation, auto-indent

It doesn't act like Python's IDLE.

Example:

```
else:  
    name = 'World'
    print 'Howdy', name
    print 'yay'
```

but in Notepad++

```
else: # i press enter and this is what it does
lands me here
```

But I want to be able to do it like in IDLE: after the `:` I can just press enter and keep on going.

I have my file type set to Python and my format to unix.

Answer (score 51):

This is what you want:

Settings > Preferences > MISC. > Auto-Indent (checkbox)

--

Sometimes people ask, "How can I do x in program y?"

I have a dream that one day "Use program z instead" will not be the most popular response.

Comment: Doesn't work, unfortunately; even with the option enabled, it does not indent correctly.  There's a reason people suggested using a different editor than TextPad.

Comment: Not working for me, either. But the Python Indent plugin mentioned by @Peter McElhinney works great.

Answer (score 38):

I played a bit with python in Notepad++ and I had a problem with the tab. 
Since in python your indentation is really important but notepad ++ put space instead of a tab.

So to change to tab you need to go in notepad ++ Menu **Settings > Preferences...** then select **Tab Settings** Then select **python** in the **Tab Settings** box and uncheck **Use default value** and check **Replace by space**.

Like the other answer, you might want to consider another ide.
I personally use eclipse with the pydev plugin and django plungin.
Erik is nice too.

Comment: I've just discovered this option (I was wondering why in Python it automatically changes to space indentation instead of tab). Anyway, is there any option to tell Notepad++ to automatically detect the tab setting in a file (i.e. if it's already indented with tab, then continue with tab - that's where Sublime really excels)

Answer (score 20):

I found the Python Indent plugin on the official plugin page, and it worked fine!

http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Plugin_Central#P

Comment: The link is dead. Here's the most recent snapshot from the Wayback Machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20190618000144/http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Plugin_Central

Answer (score 12):

Well, here is a updated answer:

Notepad++ >> Plugins >> plugin manager >> show plugin manager >> find (python indent) click install >> should be downloaded you need to reach to enable again from Plugins>>python indent>>enable

Answer (score 3):

Go to Settings > Preferences > Language

Then on the "Tab Settings" box select "python"
and tick the "Use default value" checkbox.

You're welcome.

P.S. Yeah, I know this a little old. I really just couldn't help it.
Anyway, this is for version v7.3.2.

Answer (score 2):

None of the above solutions worked for me but this worked:

- Install latest version of notepad++ (as of Feb 2022)
- Goto Settings -> Preferences -> Language -> Tab Settings -> Select Python -> Uncheck (Default Value) and make sure that the 'Replace by space' is selected with 4 as the count
- Next, goto Settings -> Preferences -> Auto-Completion -> Enable Auto-Indent (if it's not already enabled)

This should work as expected as it's working for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is for Notepad++ version v8.1.9.3 (the latest as of today)

Before starting this, save your work... but no need to close any open tab

## First; install the plugin

Plugins > Plugins Admin > Search: **Python Indent** > Python Indent (*check box*) > Install > Yes

Notepad++ will restart... it will take 10 seconds or so

## Second; enable the plugin

Plugins > Python Indent > Enable

## Third; Have fun!

Do a test... and let me know

Answer (score 0):

1. Click on *Settings*
2. Click *Preferences...*
3. Browse drop-down menu to find *MISC.*
4. Tick the box which says *Auto-indent*

After that, you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Restart Notepad++ after, and then it works.

Answer (score 0):

-- For Newer Versions , Goto **Settings>>Preferences>>Auto-Completion>>Auto-Indent(checkbox)**

-- For Older Versions , Goto **Settings > Preferences > MISC. > Auto-Indent (checkbox)**

By the time of this post, The newest Version of Notepad++ is v7.8.7.(tested)

Answer (score 0):

In Notepad++ version v8.4.4
The Auto Indent is located in Settings->Preferences->Auto-Completion
and no longer in MISC.
However, for Python indentation it didn't work for me.
What worked is to use the Python Indent plugin (set to Enable).
[image: Auto-Indent]

[image: Python-Indent Plugin]

Answer (score -3):

I've found Notepad++ to live up to the task of being a better basic text editor than Notepad, but it isn't really designed to be as smart as a proper programming IDE.

It might be possible to get it to do what you're asking for, but I certainly don't know how to set it up that way.

Answer (score -4):

Emacs has python-mode which (also) does it. Grab it and prepare for life-time enjoyment.