# How to indent a block of Python code in Notepad++?

Tags: python, notepad++, indentation

While coding in `Matlab`, I had the option of smart indenting my code using the shortcut  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>. Is there a similar option for `Python` using `Notepad++`?

Specifically, I am looking for a solution to the following problem:
I want the block

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

to be converted to

```
    line 1
    line 2
    line 3
```

On a side-note, I found this to be surprisingly easy with SE editor (keyboard shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>). I want this feature to be available for other languages as well (in my experience good indentation hasn't killed anyone, regardless of the language).

Comment: Select all 3 lines and hit the TAB key...

Comment: Could you post that as an answer? I will accept it soon. I was not able to find this solution using Google. I am looking for a different solution as well. Your solution adds `tabs`. Ideally I am looking for a solution that will add 4 spaces. But this works great!

Comment: related: [Automatic indentation for Python in Notepad++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5532549/automatic-indentation-for-python-in-notepad)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just select the text you want indented and hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>. To un-indent, select the text and hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

If you're in "Normal text file" mode, this will give you tabs (`\t` characters). If, however, you're in Python mode (which you enter either by saving as a `.py` file or by selecting Python from the Language menu), it should default to using four spaces instead of tabs. To configure the way tabs work yourself, go to Settings → Preferences → Tab Settings (for Python, this should default to "Tab size: 4" with "Replace by space" checked).

Comment: Definitely change it to spaces! Tabs suck, and they don't seem to display properly on SO.

Comment: I like *spaces* for Python, but *tabs* for C and Java. I wish there were profiles that you could set up for the language you are working with.

Answer (score 2):

Select all 3 lines and hit the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key. To undo this action you can hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> while pressing the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key.

**Pro Tip:** As long as you have at least 2 lines partially selected, you can tab in the entire block.

Example:

[image]

If you want to change tab settings there are two locations in ***Settings -> Preferences***

1. Under ***Tab Settings***: You can change the tab size and you can check off the ***Replace by space*** option if you want NPP to use spaces for tabs.
2. Under ***MISC***: you can check-off ***Auto-indent*** in case you have that option turned off.

Comment: And shift-tab de-indents.