# python, writing nested for loop

Tags: python

I am newbie to python.  I want to run this code but getting syntax error, I don't know how to fix it.  I am running it on

http://mathcs.holycross.edu/~kwalsh/python/

```
 names=['A','B','C']       
 cars=['mercedes','porshe','hyundai'] 
 numbers=[1,2,3]   
        for name in names:   
           file_name=names+".txt"
           text_file = open(file_name, "w")                   
           for car in cars:   
             print(cars)                    
             for number in numbers:   
              txt2write=name+" has "+str(number)+" "+car 
              print(name+" has "+str(number)+" "+car)
              text_file.write("%s \n" %(txt2write))


text_file.close()           
print("That's all.")
```

Any idea? Again said, its my first code..  (as said  i am totally new to Python and know nothing about nested loop)

Comment: Can you please update the answer reporting the Error? That would help

Comment: Can you please fix the indentation ..

Comment: Is this the real formatting of your code?

Comment: Correct indentation is vital in Python. BTW, since you're just starting I recommend just doing output to the terminal at this stage, using `print` rather than writing files. You don't want to make a mistake and accidentally overwrite important files on your HD!

Comment: Which book / tutorial are you learning Python from? Whatever it is, it's teaching you some pretty old-fashioned stuff. And I advise that you do **not** use that online Python interpreter you linked to. It's rather limited, and it's for Python 2, you should be learning Python 3. Ideally, you should install Python 3 on your system, but if you need an online interpreter please use one that supports Python 3, eg [compileonline](http://www.compileonline.com/execute_python3_online.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The indentation is not correct, also the line `file_name = names + "txt"` should use `name` instead of `names`. This is the full fixed code:

```
names=['A','B','C']       
cars=['mercedes','porshe','hyundai'] 
numbers=[1,2,3]   
for name in names:   
    file_name=name+".txt"
    text_file = open(file_name, "w")                   
    for car in cars:   
        print(cars)                    
        for number in numbers:   
            txt2write=name+" has "+str(number)+" "+car 
            print(name+" has "+str(number)+" "+car)
            text_file.write("%s \n" %(txt2write))
    text_file.close()     

print("That's all.")
```

Comment: how can I  correct indentation using notepad++.

Comment: you can just copy and paste this code but can change np++ settings as discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5532549/automatic-indentation-for-python-in-notepad to do it automatically

Comment: Also, you might as well just print `txt2write`, rather than re-building the exact same string in the `print` call.

Answer (score 0):

```
names=['A','B','C']
cars=['mercedes','porshe','hyundai']
numbers=[1,2,3]
for name in names:
    file_name=name+".txt" # leave 4 spaces for the outermost level
    text_file = open(file_name, "w")
    for car in cars:
        print(cars) # leave 8 spaces for the innermost level
        for number in numbers:
            txt2write=name+" has "+str(number)+" "+car
            print(name+" has "+str(number)+" "+car)
            text_file.write("%s \n" %(txt2write))
    text_file.close()
print("That's all.")
```

Get the indentation correct for the for loops.

Also `file_name=names+".txt"` is supposed to be `file_name=names+".txt"`

For reference - https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: You also need to get your indentation correct. ;)

Comment: copy-pasted from editor :(, got messed up here, fixed now.

Comment: No, it's still wrong. The `text_file.write` call isn't inside the inner loop, but it should be.